# What reference books or papers address Frobenius groups: in particular, of order (121)(120)?

Tags: finite-groups, frobenius-groups

I have constructed (as a permutation group on 121 points) a Frobenius group of order (121)(120) with kernel K = $C_{11}^2$ and cyclic complement H of order 120. I have checked its properties very carefully, and also asked a colleague (an algebraist and professor of mathematics in North Carolina) to double-check it for me. He input my data to a program designed for group calculations, confirming it as a Frobenius group. There can be no mistake. Yet I understand there is a Frobenius group of this order and this kernel whose complement is not cyclic. Either there are two such non-isomorphic groups (which I believe is impossible) or the latter group does not exist. Can anyone point me to an authoritative reference that resolves this question?

Comment: Look at Wikipedia on Frobenius Groups: "If H is the group $SL _2(F_5)$ of order 120, it acts fixed point freely on a 2-dimensional vector space $K$ over the field with 11 elements. The extension $K.H$ is the smallest example of a non-solvable Frobenius group".

Comment: There are four non-isomorphic Frobenius groups of order $14520$.  In addition to the one with cyclic complement that you've constructed, three have non-abelian complement.

Comment: Thank you, James. My colleague determined that SL(2,5) as well as "my" group were both valid, but there are two more as well? I'll have to examine my own analyses more closely.